# Numpy: Fastest Way to Fill Co-Occurrence Matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a long list of index tuples (lots of duplicates), and a matrix of n by n indices. Each tuple represents a co-occurrence.

For instance:

```
a = np.zeros(shape=(indexCount,indexCount))
```

I have tried this:

```
for i1,i2 in coocPairs:  #for instance (2374, 22003)
   a[i1][i2}+=1  #takes way too long
```

or:

```
np.put(a,coocPairs,1) #which obviously does not increment
```

or also:

```
np.add(a,coocPairs,1) #which takes even longer.
```

In an ideal world, there would be a function that takes my list of tuples, and builds a cooccurrence matrix with it, but alas (doc. isnt very helpful). I think the solution could be more on the python side of the code, but I run out of ideas. Any help welcome. Thank you for your time,

Comment: quickest solution so far:
`neighbourPairs=[a+(b*wordCount) for a,b in neighbourPairs];a = np.bincount(neighbourPairs)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `collections.Counter` to get the values that will actually appear in the matrix. This works because tuples are hashable. The assignment becomes pretty straightforward:

```
counts = collections.Counter(coocPairs)
ind = np.array(list(counts.keys())).T
a[ind[0], ind[1]] = list(counts.values())
```

As a rule, `np.unique` with `return_counts=True` is a standin for a `Counter`. In this case, it is necessary to specify the axis, and to keep in mind that it will be one of the slower solutions:

```
ind, count = np.unique(coocPairs, return_counts=True, axis=0)
a[ind.T[0], ind.T[1]] = count
```

Instead, you can transform your pairs into linear indices in the raveled matrix:

```
ind = np.ravel_multi_index(tuple(np.array(coocPairs).T), a.shape)
```

Now you can do

```
ind, count = np.unique(ind, return_counts=True)
a.ravel()[ind] = count
```

Alternatively, you can use [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) to get the counts much faster, or `np.add.at` to avoid the up-front counting. The `bincount` solution with the raveled index saves you the trouble of preallocating `a`:

```
ind = np.ravel_multi_index(tuple(np.array(coocPairs).T), (n, n))
a = np.bincount(ind, minlength=n * n).reahape(n, n)
```

Comment: Small correction: `unique` with `axis` does not work elmtwise; it can be used here, but is slow

Comment: @MadPhysicist the combination of converting my cooccurences into 1-D indices and then feeding them to a bincount function proved to be very efficient for my purpose. I had already tried Counter (bit too slow). Thanks to you and Paul for helping

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.add.at`

```
np.add.at(a,tuple(coocPairs.T),1)
```

If that's not fast enough there are faster but less straight-forward `np.bincount` based solutions. Those rely on flattened indexing using `np.ravel_multi_index`.

Comment: Hi Paul. What is the ".T" after coocPairs? it seems to be referring to a transposed matrix, yet coocPairs is a list of tuples, and has no such attribute. Could you elaborate? I'm also interested in those faster solutions! Thanks

Comment: @AudyCed Yes `X.T` gives the transpose of array `X`. If `X` is not an array you can either use `tuple(zip(*coocPairs))` or `tuple(np.transpose(coocPairs))`

Comment: Would `c = np.array(coocPairs).T; a[c[0], c[1]] += 1` work? I'm on mobile, so can't test.

Comment: @MadPhysicist not if there are duplicates.